How to get in python collision events?
Lately thanks to Ai, I can develop some code to help Me with creating some stuff to My workflows. But I stuck because of finding any method to know the collision... for example from particles, or from Rigid Body, to know that an object collided. I tried workarounds, but nothing seem to catch anything..
How it can be done, what to use here? The best for both, rigid bodies and particles.
Regards,
Camil.
